# Set cookie from main domain for subdomain

Tags: php, cookies

I have a website, consisting of three domains: `domain.com`, `sub1.domain.com` and `sub2.domain.com`.

I now want to get via AJAX on sub1.domain.com a page on domain.com which sets a cookie. This cookie has to be available to all three domains.

I've tried: `setcookie('name','value',time()+3600,'/','.domain.com');` and I've tried: `setcookie('name','value',time()+3600,'/','domain.com');` (watch the dot before the domain, I was told that old browsers wouldn't accept it.) But this didn't work. In fact, there isn't a cookie set.

How can I set a cookie on an AJAX request from a subdomain? I already added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to the setcookie-page.

Comment: In order to send cross-domain cookies, you'll need the [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) flag. Depending on the request method, you may also need `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

Comment: I added it to the code, but the problem is the same.

Comment: I'll clarify in a proper answer.

Comment: I am not sure but what about ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are required when using credentials:

- `withCredentials` flag

The AJAX request needs to have `xhr.withCredentials = true;` set.

- `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`

The server must also respond with `header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');`.

- **Wildcard origin not allowed**

When specifying `withCredentials`, the server cannot allow an origin of `*`. Therefore, you must respond with a list of valid domains:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sub1.domain.com,http://sub2.domain.com');
```

If you still want to have an arbitrary list of subdomains, you could do something like the following:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], -11) === '.domain.com') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
}
```

This sets the allowed origin to the value of the `Origin` request header, but only if it's on your domain.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was just starting to draft an edit to that effect :-)

Comment: No worries! FYI, Google Chrome gives quite helpful error messages on the console for these scenarios.